# Update/Inner Join limiting fields for efficiency sake

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I generally do updates between tables as:

```
Update TableA as A
Inner Join TableB as B
On A.Field1=B.Field1
Set A.Field2=B.Field2
```

However with my current tables this is taking forever even though I have indexed the 'On' fields in both tables which generally makes that update very fast. TableA is 2Million records but that never really mattered before, possibly because at least one field is a long text field, I am not sure.  In any event is there a way to just select the necessary fields from TableA? I get I do so on the Inner Join with

`Inner Join (Select ID,Field1,Field2 from TableB) as B`

but am unclear how do to so with the Update TableA which is the table that is giving me the issue I believe (due to the # of records, # of fields and # of full-text fields)

Comment: Doesn't matter if you are trying to use an index because you are doing a full table scan on table a.  There is no where that says "and A.something = '[some value here]'.  As a consequence, as you have more and more rows in table A, it's going to take longer.  Number of fields is meaningless.  Your statement says "update every row where A.field1 = b.field1 and a.field2 = b.field2".  At best, you might get a hash.  At worst, a temp table with all rows that satisfy in it.  If your disk is getting full, yes, that temp table will have an effect if your memory can't handle the data volume.

Comment: @TGray So I might benefit from adding ram to my server to solve this issue?